# Web scrape a a title after a specific class by python

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to scrape some information about the positions, artists and songs from a ranking list online. Here is the ranking list website: https://kma.kkbox.com/charts/weekly/newrelease?terr=my&lang=en

I'm was trying to use the following code to scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://kma.kkbox.com/charts/weekly/newrelease?terr=my&lang=en')
print(page.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
all_songs = soup.find_all(class_="charts-list-song")
all_artists = soup.find_all(class_="charts-list-artist")
print(all_songs)
print(all_artists)
```

However, the output only shows:

```
[<span class="charts-list-desc">
<span class="charts-list-song"></span>
<span class="charts-list-artist"></span>
</span>, <span class="charts-list-desc">
<span class="charts-list-song"></span>
...
```

and

```
<span class="charts-list-song"></span>, <span class="charts-list-song"></span>, <span class="charts-list-song"></span>, <span class="charts-list-song"></span>, <span class="charts-list-song"></span>, <span class="charts-list-song"></span>,
```

My expected output should be:

```
Pos    artist            songs   
1      張哲瀚             洪荒劇場Primordial Theater
2      張哲瀚             冰川消失那天Lost Glacier
3      告五人             又到天黑
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `view source` in Chrome, you can see that the actual chart content is at the end of the html source code and loaded as `chart` variable.

code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, re

page = requests.get('https://kma.kkbox.com/charts/weekly/newrelease?terr=my&lang=en')
print(page.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select('script')[-2].string
m = re.search(r'var chart = (\[{.*}\])', data)
songs = json.loads(m.group(1))
for song in songs:
    print(song['rankings']['this_period'], song['artist_name'], song['song_name'])
```

output

```
1 張哲瀚 洪荒劇場Primordial Theater
2 張哲瀚 冰川消失那天Lost Glacier
3 告五人 又到天黑
4 孫盛希 Shi Shi 眼淚記得你 (Remembered)
5 陳零九 Nine Chen 夢裡的女孩 (The Girl)
6 告五人 一念之間
7 苏有朋 玫瑰急救箱
8 林俊傑 想見你想見你想見你
...
```

Comment: May I ask how to extract it as an excel file as well?

Comment: Save it as a `.csv` file or use `pandas` module.